# C#/.NET - why is string[] castable to object[] but int[] is not?

Tags: c#, .net, types

```
var isTrue = new string[0] is object[];
var isFalse = new int[0] is object[];
```

I know the difference between value types and reference types, but **why does this behavior make sense**? Especially since:

```
var isTrue = "3" is object;
var isAlsoTrue = 3 is object;
```

Comment: Check this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/

Comment: The tl;dr is that value-type arrays are not covariant, where as reference type arrays always are. Along with @MistyK's link, you may find [this helpful as well](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/06/22/array-covariance-not-just-ugly-but-slow-too/), with the most relevant text being "There is not a reference conversion between value type arrays." I'll see if I can dig up the relevant part of the spec.

Comment: The spec included with Visual Studio outlines Array Covariance in section 12.5, with the following about value-types: "Array covariance specifically does not extend to arrays of value-types. For example, no conversion exists that permits an int[] to be treated as an object[]." As for why that's the case, I imagine there's a swift and unexpected overhead from having to box all the elements of `int[]` to `object[]` that makes allowing it undesirable- but that's just conjecture on my part.

Comment: thx homies -- I figured it had already been answered, but I couldn't concoct the right search terms :)